# SipManager.newInstance(this) returns null

Tags: android, sip

I follow instruction [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/sip.html) step by step, but when I want to get a new instance of sip manager it return null!

my device is LG G4 running android 6.0. I can run third party sip applications from google play so it means my device do support sip. but why this line return null?

```
SipManager manager = SipManager.newInstance(this);
```

Comment: I took code from android git  examples , same bug .

Answer (score 0):

I answered the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50417069/1701347) in detail.

Android SIP API is not supported on all devices. This [article](http://obem.be/2014/06/04/sip-on-android.html) discuss this problem in detail and suggest alternative solutions.