# SipManager.newInstance returns null

Tags: android, sip, android-7.0-nougat

I implement simple SIP client app for receiving calls. I go through [official manual](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/sip.html) and get code from it.

I noticed that

```
SipManager.newInstance(getApplicationContext());
```

returns null. [Documentation says](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/sip/SipManager.html#newInstance(android.content.Context)) that it happens when SIP API is not supported by device. However I use LG G6 with Android 7.0 and I successfully test third-party SIP clients from Google Play. So I doubt that API is not supported really. How could I check that?

My manifest has all permissions (`INTERNET` and `USE_SIP`)

Permission for `USE_SIP` is granted by user

Comment: Check if SIP is dangerous permission

Comment: @RahulKumar it is. Now what? They say that user should grant permission but I app doesn't suggest it

Comment: You will have to ask user to grant permission.

Comment: @RahulKumar it didn't help. user gives a permission USE_SIP but newInstance still return null after that

Answer (score 4):

The Problem is that Android SDK is not supported over all the devices.
you can check first whether it is supported on current device:

```
 if(SipManager.isVoipSupported(getApplicationContext())){
     Log.d("VOIP:", "Supported!");
 }
 else{
     Log.d("VOIP:", "Not Supported");
 }
 if(SipManager.isApiSupported(getApplicationContext())){
     Log.d("API:", "Supported!");
 }
 else{
     Log.d("API:","NotSupported!");
 }
```

Sometime API is supported but not VOIP. I tested on `Moto E 2nd Gen.` and `Moto X 2014, 1st Gen.` Both API and VOIP is not supported on Moto X and Only API is supported on Moto E, but VOIP is not.
To avoid this caveat, you can use 3rd party APIs such as [Doubango](http://www.doubango.org).

**Source**: [SIP on Android](http://obem.be/2014/06/04/sip-on-android.html): This Article discusses this problem in detail and suggest alternative APIs.